# Has the Reactive Extensions library been discontinued?

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive, reactive

[image: Screenshot of Reactive Extensions documentation website in a browser]

The documentation for much of the Reactive Extensions library on Microsoft's website says "We're no longer updating this content regularly. Check the Microsoft Product Lifecycle for information about how this product, service, technology, or API is supported."

Furthermore, searching for some basic Reactive Extensions class names (such as "Subject") in the main documentation site returns no hits.  The only hits come in the "Previous Versions" section of the site.

There is no mention of Reactive Extensions in the linked "Product Lifecycle" page.

Does this mean that Microsoft are no longer supporting Reactive Extensions, or have I missed something?

Comment: Most probably it is being moved in some other library

Comment: The *old docs* have been discontinued. You're looking at a page under the `Previous Versions` heading

Comment: Indeed, but the "new docs" have absolutely no reference to Reactive Extensions.  They're only visible in the Previous Versions section.

I've edited my post to make this clear.

Answer (score 8):

No, it hasn't. You're looking at a page under the `Previous Version` heading. That's why the warning is shown.

Reactive Extensions is a *separate* OSS project, and only the .NET implementation can be found under the `dotnet` organization. The [ReactiveX](https://github.com/ReactiveX) org contains many other implementations. If you check its [Github repo](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive) you'll see the latest commit was yesterday. The latest version [4.3.2](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Reactive/) was released to NuGet 20 days ago

The project's documentation page is http://reactivex.io/.

The project covers *many* languages, not just .NET. In fact, Reactivex.JS is probably *THE* most active edition, and most JavaScript developers don't even know Rx was created by Microsoft.

Rx is not deployed as part of .NET but then, neither is EF, EF Core, or any of a number of libraries people think as part of .NET. Lately, even Microsoft.Data.SqlClient became a separate package.

Since 4.x, many libraries became packages to reduce the runtime size *and* allow independent development.

Comment: Ah.  So Microsoft no longer include it as part of .Net?  Or, Microsoft no longer support documentation for it?

Comment: Neither (it never was *part* of .NET in any case). It's a separate OSS project, developed and supported by *many* people and organizations. Check the correct landing page http://reactivex.io/

Comment: However the interfaces IObservable & IObserver are included in .Net and can be used for public API without Rx being exposed!

Comment: @FelixKeil IObservable is to Rx what IEnumerable is to LINQ. Simply using the interface gives none of the features of the library, nor does it say anything about its support status

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I am in total consent with you. This is just an important info for application design and may be a key point for the decision in using Rx.